# Ecommerce website using php checkout situation

Tags: php, mysqli

I am developing an Ecommerce website and I have one doubt in my mind. Suppose user added a product in his cart and clicked on checkout and he is transfered to a payment gateway which arises some conditions

1. At the same time another user 2 checking out the same product while the  user 1 is in checkout process , so should i display the  product quantity one less or should i display the same quantity until the user 1 successfully make the payment.
2. What if user 1 clicked on checkout and never came back from a gateway like he has closed the browser or a tab and i have deducted the quantity when he clicked on checkout button so that user 2 can see the actuall quantity available.
3. if i don't deduct the quantity when checkout button is clicked and user 2 has also checked out just after the user 1 and product is having limited quantity which have been bought by user 1.

How to handle this situation?
I am using php and mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to deduct the quantity only when the checkout is finished.

The user who finish the checkout last will receive an error explaining that the product isn't available anymore.

Another approach used by e-commerces is [JIT](https://saleswarp.com/just-in-time-jit-inventory-management-what-role-does-it-play-for-retailers/)(Just-in-time), so the product is "always available" and this problem will not happens.

Comment: In this situation when user 2 came back on my website and my script for deducting the quantity starts running and it found that quantity is already 0 so it should display some error messge like your transaction is successful but product is no more available, your money will be transfered to your bank account in some working days right? But what i want is that transaction should never be happen whenever product is getting out of stock.

Comment: Okay, got it now... 

In this case, you should save the order and deduct the quantity before payment stage.

The payment stage comes after, when the order is already in your database. So you should reserve the products for that order before payment and save the order with a status like "Waiting for payment".

When the order stays on it for more than X days you should cancel the order and return the reserved quantities to available quantities.

The e-commerce that I am currently working is using this approach. 

I hope this solve your problem, so i can edit the answer above.